# how to clear SublimeREPL window in Sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm using SublimeREPL in Sublime 2 (v2.0.2) under OS X. I send Python files to the SublimeREPL window for evaluation, and I'd like to clear the SublimeREPL window from time to time. The window seems to be read-only, so cmd-a, delete doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> on a linux/osx system; on windows it's <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

SublimeRepl documentation is here [SublimeRepl keys](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
Linux   OS X    Windows     Command used    Meaning
Alt+p   Ctrl+p  Alt+p   repl_view_previous  Walk back to previous input, no autocomplete
Down    Down    Down    repl_view_next  Walk back to next input, with autocomplete
Alt+n   Ctrl+n  Alt+n   repl_view_next  Walk back to next input, no autocomplete
Enter   Enter   Enter   repl_enter  Send current line to REPL
Esc     Esc     Esc     repl_escape     Clear REPL input
Ctrl+l  Ctrl+l  Shift+Ctrl+c    repl_clear  Clear REPL screen
Shift+Ctrl+c    Shift+Ctrl+c    Unsupported     subprocess_repl_send_signal     Send SIGINT to REPL
```